# Error in fedex shipping method in magento

Tags: php, magento, fedex

I want to implement fedEx shipping method in my magento site. I create account on Fedex Developer Resource Center.After FedeEx Web Services for Shipping my test account id is generated. Then I write it in magento configuration fedEx shipping method.[image]

Then select shipping methods- 2 day freight,freight,3 day freight,home delivery,National freight,Ground  and select free method -home delivery.
 Now I save my setting. After saving May it fill default value.[image]
So I get the error Message-This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.
How can I configure fedEx shipping method in magento. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is not an error than why I am seeing this error message.  How can I remove it and show fedEx shipping method in my site.

Comment: did you added weight for product? Actually without weight fedEx/USPS shipping method will not show in frontend.

Answer (score 1):

If you are use the fedex magento account with india country then its not supported so please download the latest shipping API from here

http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/index.html and login.

1)      Click on FedEx Web Services and then click on Develop and Test

2)      Generate Test Credentials by clicking on Obtain Test Key button (Select US and Global from the drop down)

3)      Download the Sample Codes and Documentation by clicking on Documentation and Downloads link (Tracking Code (Track) and Rating (Rate) is available in Standard Services Tab and Shipping Code (Create Shipment) is available in Advanced Services Tab)

and update Magento API with GDE->INDIA->Shippingv17 api